How to extend lower vertices in model to x-y layer
I was able to get an STL of a racetrack with elevation variation. The mesh is therefore varying in all 3 axes. I want to extend the lower vertices of the mesh to the x-y layer. Is there an efficient way to do this?
I can only think of selecting the lowest vertices of the mesh and setting the z-coordinate to 0 but this means selecting thousands of vertices.
I tried to select by mouse looking from the bottom up but of course this also selects lots of other vertices. I tried to set up a python script to check for similar x-y coordinates and then check if there is a lower z coordinate but this is also very error prone.
Is there some simpler method I am missing?
Here is a screenshot of the mesh to help visualize it


Hello. Maybe check every edge of the mesh. If the Z coordinate of both vertices linked to this edge are more than x units, select the bottom most one and add it to your list.

I haven't found a foolproof solution to only select the right vertices, however I used a script to sort the vertices by x and y coordinates in a list, and then calculate the moving average of the Z coordinate over the next 20 or so vertices. Then only the vertices are selected, which have a Z coordinate below this value.
With this approach there were still a few vertices, which were not selected or false positives, but those could be corrected manually within a relatively short time.

Could also select all vertices that are attached to a face pointing globally downward (face normal z component > -0.9 for instance)
